# ValueError: Found array with 1 sample(s) (shape=(1, 2)) while a minimum of 2 is required by AgglomerativeClustering

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to predict unseen data

```
enter code here`
   from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
   hc = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters = 5, affinity = 'euclidean', linkage = 'ward')
   y = hc.fit(X)

   X.shape
   (200,2)
```

when I try to predict for unseen data

```
   a = int(input('Enter Income (K$)'))
   b = int(input('Enter spending score (1-100)'))
   c = np.zeros((1,2))
   c[0,0] = a
   c[0,1] = b
   print(c.shape)
   print(c)
   print(type(c))
   o = y.fit_predict(c)
   if o == 4:
       Category = 'Sensible Clients'
   elif o == 3:
       Category = 'Careless Client'
   elif o == 2:
       Category = 'Target Client'
   elif o == 1:
       Category = 'Standard Client'
   else:
       Category = 'Careful Client'
   print('The client belongs to {} Category'.format(Category))
```

Enter Income (K$)90
Enter spending score (1-100)90
(1, 2)
[[90. 90.]]'
'ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
I am trying to predict unseen data

```
enter code here`
   from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
   hc = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters = 5, affinity = 'euclidean', linkage = 'ward')
   y = hc.fit(X)

   X.shape
   (200,2)
```

when I try to predict for unseen data

```
   a = int(input('Enter Income (K$)'))
   b = int(input('Enter spending score (1-100)'))
   c = np.zeros((1,2))
   c[0,0] = a
   c[0,1] = b
   print(c.shape)
   print(c)
   print(type(c))
   o = y.fit_predict(c)
   if o == 4:
       Category = 'Sensible Clients'
   elif o == 3:
       Category = 'Careless Client'
   elif o == 2:
       Category = 'Target Client'
   elif o == 1:
       Category = 'Standard Client'
   else:
       Category = 'Careful Client'
   print('The client belongs to {} Category'.format(Category))
```

Enter Income (K$)90
Enter spending score (1-100)90
(1, 2)
[[90. 90.]]'
'ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      7 print(c)
      8 print(type(c))
----> 9 o = hc.fit_predict(c)

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in fit_predict(self, X, y)
    445         # non-optimized default implementation; override when a better
    446         # method is possible for a given clustering algorithm
--> 447         self.fit(X)
    448         return self.labels_
    449

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\hierarchical.py in fit(self, X, y)
    803                           ' It has been deprecated in version 0.20 and will be'
    804                           'removed in 0.22', DeprecationWarning)
--> 805         X = check_array(X, ensure_min_samples=2, estimator=self)
    806         memory = check_memory(self.memory)
    807

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    548                              " minimum of %d is required%s."
    549                              % (n_samples, array.shape, ensure_min_samples,
--> 550                                 context))
    551 
    552     if ensure_min_features > 0 and array.ndim == 2:

ValueError: Found array with 1 sample(s) (shape=(1, 2)) while a minimum of 2 is required by AgglomerativeClustering'